# Function that allows the user to specify title and words for a text and keep them also outside the function?

Tags: python, input

To define a text and its title, usually I do:

```
Story="I was a good boy"
```

But I would like to create a function that allows the user to type a title for a text and keep the title outside the function, for further use.

Here what I created so far:

```
def create_text():

x=input("Text title: ")
y=input("Text : ")
x=y
return x
```

When I run the code:

```
>>> create_text()
Text title: Story
Text : I was a good boy
'I was a good boy'
```

And it's ok. 
But when I type again the Text title outside the function, I get

```
>>> Story
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#349>", line 1, in <module>
    Story
NameError: name 'Story' is not defined
```

How can I create a function that allows the user to specify title and words for a text, and keep them also outside the function?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are trying to access a variable named `Story`, but that was never created. It was only the contents of a string. You'd have to do something like `Story = create_text()`, and then access `Story`. Or did you want the variable to _dynamically_ match the user inputted text?

Comment: Yes! I would like to transform a user inputted text to a variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a dictionary.

```
def create_text():
    x = input("Text title: ")
    y = input("Text : ")
    userinput = {x: y}
    return userinput
```

Now, when you run it, you can reference the story by its user-provided name (`'Story'`).

```
>>> userinput = create_text()
Text title: Story
Text : I was a good boy
>>> userinput['Story']
'I was a good boy'
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to me the best option!

Answer (score 2):

You need the function to return the values you want to use outside of it:

```
def create_text():
    _title = input("Text title: ")
    _text = input("Text : ")
    return _title, _text
```

`_title` and `_text` are local to the function and are not defined outside it's scope, so to use them make sure to use the return value (outside the function):

```
title, text = create_text()
# use 'title' and 'text' ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this was useful. But again, I'm not able to type the user defined Text title and have printed the user defined text. Maybe it's something that is not possibile (or even useful) to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the example I provided shows exactly how functions can be used to set up values in variables. The other way is to use mutable parameters, which is **not** what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, I get it. My bad, I'm sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: You did not provided what he asked for in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to transform a user input text into a variable.

```
def create_text():
    x=input("Text title: ")
    y=input("Text : ")
    globals()[x] = y
    return x
```

Now:

```
>>> create_text()
Text title: Story
Text : I was a good boy
'Story'
>>> Story
'I was a good boy'
>>>
```

But, notice that normally **this is not a good idea**. You're letting
your program input (which usually you don't have control with) to mess
up with your global namespace, which might influence the workings of
the rest of your script and even of Python itself -- not let say that
putting things in `globals()` is almost always bad design.

Considering that, the approach offered in the other answers are better
options (specially the "return a dictionary" IMHO).

Comment: Global variables are never really the right answer. Especially not setting them that way.

Comment: That's what he asked for, how to dynamic define a name in the function outerscope. I could add a comment saying that's not a good ideia, though.

Comment: Note that this allows the user to (inadvertent or maliciously) set arbitrary global variables and even overwrite existing ones, both of which might influence the workings of the rest of your script and even of Python itself.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys for your explanations. I don't really know very much on global variables, time to read the docs on this subject. Thank you anyway!

Comment: OP asked to be able to use the title outside the function. The proper way to do that is to either set a `title` variable in the function or create a dictionary with a `'title'` key and return that. Pinning things into the global dict is a hacky at best way to accomplish that.